# Clear whitespace in text file using bat

Tags: batch-file, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have the following batch file [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070405/batch-find-string-in-text-file-and-add-a-new-string-after-that-line/33070613#33070613)

It searches for the line that contains...

```
[/Script/MyGame.Mode]
```

Then it creates a new line and adds...

```
RedirectReferences=(PackageName="%Package%",PackageURLProtocol="%PackageURLProtocol%",PackageURL="%WebAddress%/%Package%%Ext%",PackageChecksum="")
```

It works unless the original file contains spaces after each line. If there are no spaces it works perfect.

Is there an easy way to clear out all the spaces in the original file before it searches, copies and writes the new line in a new file?

Or is there a better way to do this overall. Sorry but I'm not knowledgeable at batch files yet. Thanks for any help given.

Comment: echo it, look at what you're getting, compare that to what you're expecting. The problem is most likely some introduced quotes in a space-containing-string which you're assuming against.

Comment: please add the affected code portion herein rather than providing a link only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was able to clear the spaces from the original file with the code below before running the copy and adding the new line.

I changed some file names then ran the code below before I'm checking the file and writing new line.

I had to show some code from my other bat to show you the file name changes. Once you combine everything together in one bat it works fine.

```
:CLEARWHITESPACE
for /F "eol=; tokens=1 delims=; " %%I in (Game.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  if !count! leq 10 echo %%I>>game.temp.txt
)

:SHOWLINE
set NewURL=RedirectReferences=(PackageName="%Package%",PackageURLProtocol="%PackageURLProtocol%",PackageURL="%WebAddress%/%Package%%Ext%",PackageChecksum="")

pause

:WRITENEW
set inputfile=game.temp.txt
set outputfile=game.temp2.txt
(for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
   echo %%a 
   if "%%~a"=="[/Script/MyGame.Mode]" call echo %%NewURL%%  
))>>"%outputfile%"
```